# How can warmup/prepare the table/index statistics?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

I have a batch process, to find the `near_link` for each `avl` position. The avl distribution is random but have a normal distribution around the city. The problem is the first batch take a lot of time. But posterior batch are much faster.

The map doesnt change, so my guess is some statistics are created. Because try to search the x,y in the same map over and over again.

**So how can I help create those statistic before the batch start?** Or how I check what is happening behind the hood.

The thing is I get this result running the batch alone, and Im worry if running in the production server the statistics arent that good because are all kind of other requests to the map.

```
-- Executing query:
SELECT * FROM avl_db.process_near_link();

NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 163.4609 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 68.73396 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 36.93196 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 17.58829 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 12.94885 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 9.509757 , Rows= 400

Total query runtime: 05:09 minutes  -- 2400 rows
1 row retrieved.

-- Executing query:
SELECT * FROM avl_db.process_near_link();

NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 8.03767 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 8.51031 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 5.45953 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 4.08547 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 4.19483 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 3.85986 , Rows= 400

Total query runtime: 34.1 secs -- 2400 rows
1 row retrieved.

-- Executing query:
SELECT * FROM avl_db.process_near_link();

NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 3.66540 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 3.55134 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 3.17400 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 3.06982 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.96954 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 3.05310 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.88948 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.77269 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.88940 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.94150 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.84522 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.86770 , Rows= 400
NOTICE:  Duration in seconds= 2.74608 , Rows= 400

Total query runtime: 39.4 secs  -- 5200
1 row retrieved.
```

This is the batch query:

```
UPDATE avl_db.avl_pool a
SET near_link = map.get_near_link(sq.X, sq.Y, sq.AZIMUTH),
    has_link = true
FROM (
     SELECT avl_id, x, y, azimuth
     FROM avl_db.avl_pool
     WHERE NOT has_link
     ORDER BY avl_id
     LIMIT 400
    ) sq
    WHERE a.avl_id = sq.avl_id;
```

[**Explain Plan**](https://explain.depesz.com/s/YyKXx)

```
"Update on avl_pool a  (cost=0.84..3395.28 rows=400 width=151) (actual time=2779.889..2779.889 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..3395.28 rows=400 width=151) (actual time=11.253..2738.711 rows=400 loops=1)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on sq  (cost=0.42..34.28 rows=400 width=80) (actual time=6.882..8.496 rows=400 loops=1)"
"              ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..30.28 rows=400 width=28) (actual time=6.871..7.964 rows=400 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using avl_pool_pkey on avl_pool  (cost=0.42..29185.30 rows=391017 width=28) (actual time=6.869..7.873 rows=400 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (NOT has_link)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 10800"
"        ->  Index Scan using avl_pool_pkey on avl_pool a  (cost=0.42..8.14 rows=1 width=79) (actual time=0.003..0.029 rows=1 loops=400)"
"              Index Cond: (avl_id = sq.avl_id)"
"Planning time: 0.372 ms"
"Execution time: 2779.970 ms"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you are experiencing the effects of caching.

During the first runs, data has to be fetched from disk, later runs can profit from data already cached (blocks from the `avl_pool_pkey` index mostly, but also table blocks visited during previous updates).

You can verify this if you use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, which will show you how many blocks are read from disk and how many are found in the cache.